# How to check whether table exists in SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

if (1st table exists) then select date from 1st table and call a (procedure)
how to do this?

Comment: `swl` (in your title) !?!?!? What/who is that ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 7):

I like this method for checking an objects existence.

```
IF Object_ID('dbo.your_table', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    /* Table exists */
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    /* Table does not exist */
  END
```

The [`Object_ID()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx) function returns the... object_id(!) of the specified object. If the object doesn't exist then it returns `NULL`. The second [optional] parameter being passed here is a **`U`** which is the object *type* (U=User table, V=View, P=Procedure... see **type** column here for more info [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx)).

Basically this is a short hand (lazy? *ahem*) method of checking for an objects existence

Comment: ***assumed*** this was for SQL Server... Apologies if not!

Answer (score 1):

Verify if the table exists before proceeding;

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[YourTable]') AND type in (N'U'))
```